# CSS hover pseudo-class and canvas interaction?

Tags: html, css

Having an issue where if you try to hover over the buttons on the left side they don't work when canvas is displayed. If you switch to display:none; then the hover works fine. I don't understand why at all.

Here's the jsfiddle with all the code. Funny enough, it works in jsfiddle but it doesn't work in chrome,ie or firefox. 
https://jsfiddle.net/9nc22xuy/

Edit:#openscene is the canvas ID

```css
.mode{
  width:200px;
  background:#e3e3e3;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #333;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  margin-left:22.5px;
  transition: all 400ms
}

#openscene{
  background:black;
  margin-right:250px;

  position:relative;
  left:235px;
  border-top:135px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom:135px solid #CCC;
  border-right:10px solid #ccc;
  border-left:10px solid #ccc;


}

#left-side-wrapper {
  margin-left: -250px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #CCC;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display:block;
  
}

.mode#one{
  margin-top:20px;
}

.mode:hover {
  background:#333;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="button-wrapper">
    <div class="mode" id="one">25 Card Timed</div>
      
    <div class="mode" id="two">50 Card Timed</div>

    <div class="mode" id="three">25 Card 4 Miss</div>

    <div class="mode" id="four">50 Card 4 Miss</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is "it works in jsfiddle but it doesn't work in chrome,ie or firefox"?

Comment: Meaning when the code is executed in jsfiddle the hover element works fine, but if you just open it as actual webpage in the browser it doesn't

Comment: But, but jsfiddle is a webpage just like any other. Do you have errors in the webpage that you omitted from the jsfiddle one?

Comment: jsfiddle includes the full website code at the moment so no =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.container-fluid` overlays the left menu and prevents the `:hover` effect on buttons.

Anyways, what I'd suggest as fastest tweak would be to place menu above:

- Add `z-index: 1;` to `#left-side-wrapper`.

Another would be making content inside `.container-fluid` less than 12 columns which is what collapses with left menu (try offsetting that `.col-md-12` to `.col-md-10` and `.col-md-offset-2` and you'll see you can hover again) but it would require a few classes tweak.

Comment: Perfect, Z-index was exactly what I was looking for. I had forgot I put the canvas inside the container which makes perfect sense now. Thank you!